# How to use HTML elements as triggers if they are loaded after the initial page load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok so I have done a little bit of research, and I am kinda stuck on this ajax thing.

I have two A HREFs I have on that is classed "testing" that sends the ajax call, then ".page" that acts like the actual pagination next button. When I click page button, it should change a hidden input fields value to page-2, which would act as going to page two but through ajax. For now I just have it hard coded to change to page-2 and console.log the input hidden field.

The current AJAX call doesnt send any post data, its just for testing right now, and all it does is echo out a href that is a pagination button.

Im trying to make a AJAX pagination.

When I click testing, it basically replaces the current Asdasd link (that acts like a pagiantion button) to an identical link that has Pagination as text instead of asdasd. This link should change the hidden input value, but currently because the pagination link is generated by AJAX and is loaded after the page load, the initial jQuery doesnt work and it does nothing. If I echo the same jquery out with the ajax call, it works, but the problem is, I dont want to reload the jquery script everytime an ajax is called.

I thought that I could use .ready like this:

```
$('.page').ready(function(){
     $('.asdasd, .page').on("click", function(e){

     e.preventDefault();

     if($(this).hasClass('page')){
          console.log(true);
     }

     $('.new-page').val('page-2');

     console.log($('.new-page').val());
});
```

Which I thought would always try and see if page is ready or something but that doesnt even make sense.

Pretty much the only thing I do know that works, is that I have to send the jquery script and echo it out again in each jquery call so that the HTML DOM element is reloaded and jquery recognizes it.

My question is, is there any way to load the jquery script just one time, and make it so it always picks up that pagination button even if it has been loaded after the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuerys' [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method:

> Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, *now or in the future*, based on a specific set of root elements.

```
$(document.body).delegate('.asdasd, .page', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('page')) {
        console.log(true);
    }

    $('.new-page').val('page-2');

    console.log($('.new-page').val());
});​
```

Comment: Just FYI if using jQuery 1.7 or above, `delegate` has been superseded by the `on` method... The only thing that would change is the order of the first two params I believe. See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/